# Least element of a partial order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I need help with a question concerning the least element in a partial order.

Write {0,1}* for ∪<sub>*n∈ℕ*</sub>{0,1}<sup>*n*</sup>.

Elements of {0,1}* are called *words* and subsets of {0,1}* are called *formal languages* (over the two-element alphabet {0,1}). Write ε for the empty
word (of length 0).

Consider the function *f* : P( {0,1}* ) →
P( {0,1}* ),where P refers to the powerset, defined as follows:

*f* (X) = X ∪ {*w* 01 : *w* ∈ X} ∪ {ε}.

Find the least point of f on P({0,1}*) ordered by inclusion.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is "least point of $f$" the same as "global minimum of $f$"?

Comment: I think so, yes ! and the Ps represent powersets.

Comment: So the global minimum seems to be the empty set. That's because $f(\emptyset) = \{\epsilon\}$ which (by definition of $f$) is contained in every other element from the image.

Answer (score 1):

The global minimum is the empty set $\emptyset$. Indeed, $f(\emptyset)=\{\epsilon\}$. Now for any other subset $A\in P( \{0, 1\}^*)$ we have

$$f(A) = A \cup \{w01 : w \in A\} \cup \{\epsilon\}$$

In particular $\{\epsilon\}\subseteq f(A)$ for any $A$. Note that the inclusion is proper if $A\neq\emptyset$. Thus

$$f(\emptyset) < f(A)$$
for any $A\neq\emptyset$. That completes the proof.